# Checking for multiple values with in same column

Tags: mysql, sql, filter

This is how my database table structure looks -

```
ID fieldname fieldvalue
1   country   USA
2   language  English
3   country   India
4   language  Hindi
```

So I want to select the rows where the `fieldname` is say 'country' and `fieldvalue` is `USA` AND `fieldname` is `language` and `fieldvalue` is `English`.

Basically filtering by multiple values bases on key / value pairs.

I've tried using the AND keyword but its returns nothing

Any clue ?

Comment: Such generic design is a database design one would avoid if not really, really necessary. Maybe you should change your design, so writing queries would be much easier.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I agree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `OR` operator as below

```
select *
from tab
where (fieldname = 'country' and  fieldvalue = 'USA')
or (fieldname = 'language' and  fieldvalue = 'English')
```

Comment: Yes, but the issue is it would return either country is USA or language is English, right ?

Comment: @nope, this returns the items if either field name is there or fieldvalue.

Comment: @user2475624 What do you expect in result?

Comment: I am looking for rows with both key / value matches.

Comment: @user2475624 Can you show us an output? My query returns is 1 and 2. Is it ok?

Comment: actually I'm doing join with an another table and it should return the join result only if both the fieldname, fieldvalues matches, so lets say -

select *
from tab
where (fieldname = 'country' and  fieldvalue = 'USA')
or (fieldname = 'language' and  fieldvalue = 'Spanish')

It should return nothing

Comment: @user2475624 So it's totally different problem than you asked. I need to see a query than I can help you.

Comment: @user2475624: No, you shouldn't continue in chat. You've asked a question and got an answer, and you should accept it. As Parado just said, the question you are about to ask now is completely different from the question at hand, so you should better ask a new question in a new request.

Answer (score 2):

A fieldname can't be both 'country' AND 'language' at the same time. But if you use OR, they are both true.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE ( fieldname = 'country' AND fieldvalue = 'USA' )
   OR ( fieldname = 'language' AND fieldvalue = 'English');
```